# Angular material Configuration Error and Warning Please Help me to figure out

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material 2 using cli. When i install @angular/material and include it in app.module, the compiler through 3 warnings.

what i did

> npm install --save @angular/material

other imports

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),other imports...
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Additional setup

styles.css

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

index.html

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/hammerjs/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Warnings

```
1. WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/module.js
64:4 export 'ProjectionModule' was not foun
d in './core/index'
 2. WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/module.js
89:16 export 'ProjectionModule' was not fou
nd in './core/index'
 3. WARNING in ./~/@angular/material/dialog/ind
ex.js
21:75 export 'Platform' was not found in '.
./core'
```

Error on running http://localhost:4200/

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at __extends (snack-bar-container.js:4)
    at snack-bar-container.js:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (snack-bar-container.js:122)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ff6af8…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (snack-bar-ref.js:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ff6af8…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (menu.js:40)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ff6af8…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (icon.js:264)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9ff6af8…:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules), you should import each module. I'm importing all at once during the development process, but without the .forRoot(), and works fine:

```
 imports: [
    MaterialModule,
  ],
```